# Concatenate string array as a multiple criteria for filter

Tags: excel, vba

I want to concatenate a string array inside a AutoFilter.

I just used macro recorder for this code.

I'm trying to get the same output of this and i don't want to brute force all of the possible conditions.

```
 ActiveSheet.Range("$A$8:$BH$331").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=Array( _
    "ISO 14001","ISO 45001", "ISO 9001", "OHSAS 18001", "QMET"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

But I need to concatenate each text if the condition is met.

```
Dim strStandard(0 To 5) As String    
strStandard(0) = "ISO 9001"
strStandard(1) = "ISO 14001"
strStandard(2) = "ISO 45001"
strStandard(3) = "QMET"
strStandard(4) = "OHSAS 18001"
strStandard(5) = "Combined (14K+18K)
If ISO9001.Value = True = True Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$8:$BH$331").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=ISO9001.Value
End If
If ISO14001.Value = True = True Then
 ActiveSheet.Range("$A$8:$BH$331").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:= _
   "ISO 14001"
End If
```

**strStandard will be the multiple criteria for the filter**

**My Idea is to check every checkbox if it's value is true if is true it will get the string from strStandard array and pass it to strFilterContainer for string array then a single Autofilter**

`ActiveSheet.Range("$A$8:$BH$331").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=strFilterContainer, Operator:=xlFilterValues`

**strStandard will be the multiple criteria for the filter**
Is there a way to concatenate the string array inside the AutoFilter?

Comment: What do you mean by *"concatenate the two texts inside a autofilter"* can you show a screenshot how that would look like before/after?

Comment: I can do it on one Autofilter like the code at first but I need to do it using conditional statement first. Because im using checkboxes on this one.

Comment: That's not specific enough. Which conditional statement? There is no in your question. It is very unclear what "each text" means and what the "condition" is. Please add screenshots to explain the difference.

Comment: '''If ISO9001.Value = True = True Then
       strStandard.Value = 0
       ActiveSheet.Range("$A$8:$BH$331").AutoFilter Field:=4,       Criteria1:=ISO9001.Value
End If
If ISO14001.Value = True = True Then
     ActiveSheet.Range("$A$8:$BH$331").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:= _
       "ISO 1400"
End If
'''


I want to concatenate the strings inside the Criteria1 in if both the condition is true.

Comment: It won't become more clear if you just repeat what you have already told. Please provide the information asked for. Note that code in comments is not readable and must be [edit]ed/added into the original question. Please also see what a [mcve] is.

Comment: Do you actually mean you want to be able to add or remove items to/from [the Array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-arrays) that you are filtering by?

Comment: I edited my question sorry for the confusion earlier.

Comment: What is `ISO9001` and `ISO14001` in your code? That is a not defined/declared variable.

Comment: That is the checkbox sorry for the bad naming convention. I declared it at initialization of the userform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, you need to populate your Array with the correct values.  To get an array of the correct size, you can either use `ReDim` or `Split`.

Using `Redim`:

```
Dim MyFilters() As String, ArrayLength As Long
ArrayLength = -1
If ISO9001.Value Then
    ArrayLength = ArrayLength+1
    'Resize the array
    ReDim Preserve MyFilters(0 to ArrayLength)
    'Add option to the end of the array
    MyFilters(ArrayLength) = "ISO 9001"
End If
If ISO14001.Value Then
    ArrayLength = ArrayLength+1
    'Resize the array, without clearing contents
    ReDim Preserve MyFilters(0 to ArrayLength)
    'Add option to the end of the array
    MyFilters(ArrayLength) = "ISO 14001"
End If
If ISO45001.Value Then
    ArrayLength = ArrayLength+1
    'Resize the array, without clearing contents
    ReDim Preserve MyFilters(0 to ArrayLength)
    'Add option to the end of the array
    MyFilters(ArrayLength) = "ISO 45001"
End If
'Et Cetera

'If we have items in the Filter
If ArrayLength >= 0 Then
    'Apply the Filter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$8:$BH$331").AutoFilter Field:=4, _
        Criteria1:=MyFilters, Operator:=xlFilterValues
End If
```

Using `Split`:

```
Dim FilterString As String
FilterString = ""

'Add the items to the string
If ISO9001.Value Then FilterString = FilterString & "|ISO 9001"
If ISO14001.Value Then FilterString = FilterString & "|ISO 14001"
If ISO45001.Value Then FilterString = FilterString & "|ISO 45001"
'Et Cetera

'If we have items in the Filter
If Len(FilterString) > 0 Then
    'Remove the first "|"
    FilterString = Mid(FilterString, 2)
    'Apply the Filter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$8:$BH$331").AutoFilter Field:=4, _
        Criteria1:=Split(FilterString,"|"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
End If
```

Personally, I would use `Split`, since it is less resource-intensive than `ReDim`